# SHA-256 hashing algorithm

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, sha256

Where in the Bitcoin github repo is the SHA-256 hashing algorithm defined? Is it a methematical formula?

Answer (score 5):

The SHA-256 algorithm is not *defined* in the Bitcoin GitHub repository, it is defined in the USA Federal Information Processing Standards  (FIPS) publication 180-2 (see [Wikipedia: SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)).

The *implementation* in Bitcoin Core is in [`src/crypto/sha256.cpp`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/crypto/sha256.cpp),  [`src/crypto/sha256.h`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/crypto/sha256.h)
and related source files and/or dependencies.

---

If I was looking for a definition that might include a mathematical formalism that describes the algorithm, I would read the FIPS document.

If I was looking for working C++ code available under an open source licence, I would look at the above files in the Github repository.